How to divide the memory space
10M memory is divided into 4 modules. How to code so that the size of each module is an integer multiple of 64 and the total is 10M. The following code is difficult to maintain and may not meet the requirements. How can I implement this function elegantly?
Thanks in advance!
typedef unsigned int uint32;

// 10M cache memory allocate as following
#define DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE                 ((uint32)(0.3 * 1024 * 1024)) // 0.3M
#define DP_BUF_UL_SIZE                  ((uint32)(3.5 * 1024 * 1024)) // 3.5M
#define DP_BUF_DL_SIZE                  ((uint32)(3.7 * 1024 * 1024)) // 3.7M
#define DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE              ((uint32)(2.5 * 1024 * 1024)) // 2.5M


If you mean 10,485,760 bytes, you should write that as “10 MiB”, not “10M”. Both using the correct abbreviation for a multiple (“Mi” for “mebi” = 2^20 =1,048,576, not “M” for “mega” = 1,000,000) and the units (“B” for bytes, rather than b for bits or some other unit).

In any case, partitioning of a space into whole numbers of 64 bytes is easily done by doing the arithmetic in units of 64 bytes. Divide 10,485,760 by 64 to get 163,840. Then partition the 163,840 into whole numbers as you please. (You will have to make some decisions about which partitions to round up and which to round down, since the multiplications by .3 and 2.7 will not produce whole numbers.) Once you have whole numbers of 64-byte units, multiple the size of each by 64 to get the number of bytes in that partition.

The rounding part is actually tricky and is why I am not writing an answer at the moment. Likely there are other posts addressing it. There is no universally “fair” way to deal with the rounding. If you had n partitions each intended to be equal size, 1/n of the total, the simple arithmetic for each could round down, so they would all round down, giving you n−1 extra units at the end to assign to one partition. So some algorithm has to be used to distribute the excess over multiple partitions. And, for similar cases, there will never be a completely even distribution.

Instead of ((uint32)(FACTOR * 1024 * 1024))  you can use ((uint32)(FACTOR * 1024 * 16)*64) to guarantee a multiple of 64.

Similarly to @chux's answer, I'm used to do something like this ;
#define MAX_SZ 10485760UL
#define BLOCK_SZ 64UL

#define DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE     (256 * 16 * BLOCK_SZ)
#define DP_BUF_UL_SIZE      (3072 * 16 * BLOCK_SZ)
#define DP_BUF_DL_SIZE      (4096 * 16 * BLOCK_SZ)
#define DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE  (2048 * 16 * BLOCK_SZ)

#if ((DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE + DP_BUF_UL_SIZE + DP_BUF_DL_SIZE + DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE) > MAX_SZ)
#error Too large

// Eventually
#elif ((DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE + DP_BUF_UL_SIZE + DP_BUF_DL_SIZE + DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE) % BLOCK_SZ)
#error Not multiple of 64
#endif

So the program wouldn't compile if DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE + DP_BUF_UL_SIZE + DP_BUF_DL_SIZE + DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE is superior to MAX_SZ, or if it ain't a multiple of 64.


Use multiples of 64.

Let last size use the remainder and avoid issues of using floating point math.  In other words, do not over specify.  Which is more important: does the sum add to 10M or does the last region equal  2.5 * 1024 * 1024?  This answer assumes add to 10M is more important.

Minor: use standard fixed size types.


#include <inttypes.h>

#define TEN_M ((uint32_t)1024 * 1024)  // or 1000000 or some other multiple of 64
#define BLOCK 64
#define TEN_M_BLOCKS (TEN_M/BLOCK)

#define DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE       ((uint32_t)(0.3 * TEN_M_BLOCKS) * 64) // 0.3M
#define DP_BUF_UL_SIZE        ((uint32_t)(3.5 * TEN_M_BLOCKS) * 64) // 3.5M
#define DP_BUF_DL_SIZE        ((uint32_t)(3.7 * TEN_M_BLOCKS) * 64) // 3.7M
#define DP_BUF_COMMON_SIZE    (TEN_M - DP_BUF_RSV_SIZE - DP_BUF_UL_SIZE - DP_BUF_DL_SIZE) // Remainder

FWIW, I'd expect sizes to use size_t rather than uint32_t.

Well, as 10Mb is multiple of 64, you can just divide all numbers by 64, operate on them with integer arithmetic, then multiply the result by 64 and you will have all numbers multiple of 64, and fitting in 10Mb.
There are exactly 163840 blocks of 64bytes in 10Mb :)
BTW, if you need to round up the numbers to 64byte chunks, a good approach is to:
inline unsigned
round_up64(unsigned x)
{
    x += 63;
    x -= x % 64;
    return x;
}

The returned value will allways be a rounded up multiple of 64.  This is what normally alignment functions use to compute the values to use in the chunks.
I have not used a macro because the double use of x % 64.
